# Accessing elements of a vector of ints by raw pointers

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I wonder if the code below is legal.

Basically I have a `std::vector<int>` and I have a legacy function that processes an array of `int`s. As the elements of a `std::vector` are always contiguous the code should always work (it actually works on my implementation), but it still seems bit of a hack to me.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void LecagyFunction(int *data, int length)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vector;
  vector.push_back(5);
  vector.push_back(4);
  vector.push_back(3);
  LecagyFunction(&vector[0], vector.size());
}
```

The output as expected is:

```
5
4
3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a hack, but a 100% legal (and expected) usage of vector. In C++11 your code should be rewritten to take advantage of `data()` member - which is defined for empty vectors, unlike `operator[]`.

```
LecagyFunction(vector.data(), vector.size());
```

And as a side note, above technique will not work for `vector<bool>`, since the later does not follow properties of regular vectors (a terrible idea, as everybody understands now).

Comment: C++11 way is not just "simplification": unlike the old way, it works even for empty vector.

Comment: @TartanLlama, original question is about ints, but I will clarify. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

> Just like arrays, vectors use contiguous storage locations for their
>   elements, which means that their elements can also be accessed using
>   offsets on regular pointers to its elements, and just as efficiently
>   as in arrays. But unlike arrays, their size can change dynamically,
>   with their storage being handled automatically by the container.

From: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

> The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be
>   accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets on regular
>   pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a
>   vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an
>   element of an array.

So yes, perfectly legal and intended to work in this way.